# Add css class on home route

Tags: angularjs

As in title I want to add a css class "homeClass" on my header in home page

This is my config and my attr directive

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider .when("/", {
        templateUrl: "/partial/home.html",
        isMain:true
    });
});

app.directive('animClass',function($route){
return {
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs){
        if($route.current.isMain)
            elm.addClass('homeclass');
    }
}
});
```

index.html

```
<header class="intro-header" anim-class>
...
</header>
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm pretty sure isMain isn't accessible in the directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ng-class instead because your directive will fire before your route changes:

```
app.directive('animClass',function($route){
    return {
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs){
            scope.$route = $route;
        }
    }
});
```

And then for your directive you can hook into that:

```
<header class="intro-header" anim-class ng-class="{
    'homeClass': $route.current.isMain
}">
...
</header>
```

Not sure how your `$scopes`/partials are wired up, but that would be the general idea.

Comment: it works thanks. I'm not totally sure about why, but it works :)
`scope.$route = $route;` ?